# Add search to react-native firebase list

Tags: react-native, search, firebase-realtime-database, filter, react-native-flatlist

I have a react-native list populated from firebase. I want to add a search bar on top of the app. Once I start typing, I want that list to only show results related to the search term. Its similar to this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699/

Only problem is the way my data is typed after its retrieved from firebase, its impossible to use the tutorial above to retrieve that data.

My html code is:

```
<Toolbar title="Hello World"/>
      <Button
        title="Add New"
        type = "outline"
        onPress={this.addItem.bind(this)}
      />
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.itemDataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
```

My Firebase retrieval code is as follows:

```
getItems(itemsRef) {

itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
  let items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    items.push({
      title: child.val().DESCRIPTION,
      text: child.val().BASE,
      _key: child.key
    });
  });
  this.setState({
    itemDataSource: this.state.itemDataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
  });
});
```

}

I just don't know how to add a search bar that searches the retrieved list and displays only relevant stuff on the list as someone types a word in.

Pease help. I'm guessing the type of the data is what is causing the problem.

Results should look like this App. I built this on AppSheet:

https://www.appsheet.com/start/ab7f8d5d-1adf-4107-bdd8-f7022a1a81f8